# canvas.setExtent immediately followed by canvas.extent returns different values

Tags: pyqgis

I don't understand this behavior. I was expecting that after setting the canvas extent to some rectangle, then calling the extent method would return the same rectangle. Are my results below (see comments in code) expected behavior? If it is, can someone explain the logic?

```
from qgis.core import QgsApplication, QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem, QgsRectangle
from qgis.gui import QgsMapCanvas


QgsApplication.setPrefixPath("/usr/bin/qgis", True)
qgs = QgsApplication([], False)
qgs.initQgis()

canvas = QgsMapCanvas()

#trying with different CRS makes no difference
#crs = QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem("EPSG:3857")
#crs = QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem("EPSG:25832")
#canvas.setDestinationCrs(crs)

extent = QgsRectangle(0,0,200,300)
print(canvas.extent()) # <QgsRectangle: 0 0, 0 0>
canvas.setExtent(extent)
print(canvas.extent()) # <QgsRectangle: -100.20920502092050697 0, 300.20920502092053539 300>

# result is the same after refresh and update
#canvas.refresh()
#canvas.update()
```

Using QGIS 3.24 Tisler on Ubuntu. I get the same result in both shell and the QGIS Python Console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes your results are indeed expected behaviour. The canvas extent always has to be expanded to fit the aspect ratio of the window. Otherwise the map would be completely distorted.

In the image below I have tried to visualize the extent you are giving as parameter and the actual map window size and also annotated the relevant coordinates, so that you can hopefully understand why `extent()`
returns `<QgsRectangle: -100 0, 300 300>` in your example case.

[image: extent]

Only if the map canvas size matches the aspect ratio of a given extent then `extent()` will also return the same (well not even exactly the same, as you can see below).

```py
extent = QgsRectangle(0, 0, 200, 300)
canvas.setFixedSize(extent.width(), extent.height())
canvas.setExtent(extent)
print(canvas.extent()) <QgsRectangle: 0 -0.5050505050505194, 200 300.5050505050505194>
```